# Unable to install ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ros-kinetic, installation, apt

While installing ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 22.04, I am getting the following errors :

```
The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies:
ros-kinetic-roscpp : Dependency: libboost-chrono1.58.0 but it is not installable
                     Dependency: libboost-filesystem1.58.0 but it cannot be installed
                     Depends on: libboost-system1.58.0 but it is not installable
                     Depends on: libboost-thread1.58.0 but it cannot be installed
                     Dependent: ros-kinetic-cpp-common (>= 0.3.17) but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-message-runtime but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-rosconsole but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-roscpp-serialization but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits (>= 0.3.17) but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-rosgraph-msgs (>= 1.10.3) but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-rostime (>= 0.6.4) but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-std-msgs but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-xmlrpcpp but will not be installed
 ros-kinetic-rospy : Depends on: python-numpy but will not be installed
                     Depends on: python-rospkg but will not be installed
                     Depends on: python-yaml but cannot be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-genpy but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-rosgraph but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-rosgraph-msgs (>= 1.10.3) but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-roslib but will not be installed
                     Depends on: ros-kinetic-std-msgs but will not be installed
E: Unable to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.
```

---

ok, thanks a lot for your response.
I need Ros to use gazebo and my computer.
so, I have to look another version, noetic?
Il will try to choose the more simple.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I am sorry to inform you that ROS Kinetic is no longer supported. It is strongly recommended to move to ROS 2; if you can't, please use ROS Noetic. See [here](https://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic binaries won't work on Ubuntu 22.04, they only worked on 16.04 (and 15.10 according https://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) but that is also end-of-life- if you absolutely need it you can pay Canonical for 'Extended Security Maintenance' https://ubuntu.com/robotics/ros-esm.  Otherwise you're better off with 20.04 and `noetic`, or doing a mix of the debian supported `ros-one` binaries on newer Ubuntu (or Debian) distributions including 22.04 and building other needed packages from source.